# php string replace baffled me

Tags: php, string, str-replace

This is not working, what's going on it should be so simple :-(

```
    $test = "hello naughty";


$swearWords = array("naughty","notallowed");

foreach ($swearWords as $naughty)
{
    $post = str_ireplace($naughty, "<b><i>(oops)</i></b>", $test);

}

echo $post;
```

Thanks

Comment: If in doubt, output each relevant variable at each step in your script. That would make the problem pretty obvious in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're (always) using $test as the input parameter.
In the example the needle `notallowed` in the second iteration of the foreach loop isn't found and therefore the input string `$test='hello naughty'` is returned unchanged.

```
<?php
$test = "hello naughty";
$swearWords = array("naughty","notallowed");

$post = $test;
foreach ($swearWords as $naughty)
{
    $post = str_ireplace($naughty, "<b><i>(oops)</i></b>", $post);
}

echo $post;
```

prints `hello <b><i>(oops)</i></b>`

and str_ireplace can take an array of needles as first parameter

```
<?php
$test = "hello notallowed, this is naughty";
$post = str_ireplace(array("naughty","notallowed"), "<b><i>(oops)</i></b>", $test);
echo $post;
```

prints `hello <b><i>(oops)</i></b>, this is <b><i>(oops)</i></b>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use array for replacing

```
<?php

    $test = "hello naughty";
    $swearWords = array("naughty","notallowed");
    $post = str_ireplace($swearWords, "<b><i>(oops)</i></b>", $test);
    echo $post;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$test = "hello naughty";
$swearWords = array("naughty","notallowed");
$post = str_ireplace($swearWords,"<b><i>(oops)</i></b>",$test)
echo $post;
```

instead. See [str_ireplace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php) for info on the way the function handles array parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this

```
$test = "hello naughty";


$swearWords = array("naughty","notallowed");

foreach ($swearWords as $naughty)
{
//$post = str_ireplace($naughty, "(oops)", $test);
echo str_ireplace($naughty,"<b><i>(oops)</i></b>",$test)."<br>";

}
```

Try edited code

Answer (score 0):

for supporting other answers i have several links which shows examples to help you.

May these are helpful for youand solves your problem.

http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_str_ireplace.asp

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

$swearWords = array("naughty"); 
Then it says (oops) instead of naughty.